# iTextSharp being agnostic of browser on web server

Tags: itext

We are running issues with ABCpdf where it depends on the right version of browser (IE) on the webserver to work properly. I guess it needs IE dll/engine files

Do I need a specific server of IE or Chrome on the webserver for iTextSharp to work properly

Comment: Not the user browser, but the version of browser installed on the webserver. Doesn't it need the IE dlls on the server to work properly? I know ABCpdf does (we installed IE 11 version on webserver, and ABCPDF broke, and I guess we need to upgrade to 10.1 version now), how about iTextSharp

Comment: It doesn't depend on IE as far as I know, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTextSharp's XML Worker parses the XML and converts it to PDF using iTextSharp. You don't need a browser on the server. You only need the fonts (ttf files) you plan to use in the PDFs.